# Why does my macro run on every cell that I change?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that was meant to automatically filter data from a table when the values in specific cells were applied. It also does other things, i.e., brings you back to the main sheet.

It looks like macro runs any time I do anything in any cell and I'm not sure why...

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'I made this first if function so the changes only apply to Sheet 1'
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then

'The two below were created so only cells A1 and A2 would trigger the "AutoFilter" Macro

    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
    Call AutoFilter
    End If

    If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then
    Call AutoFilter
    End If
             
End Sub
```

You may notice that the initial If the function does not have an 'End If' statement. This is because when I include it, I get an error saying "End if without a Block If", so I removed it. I don't know if this is related to the error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely want to fix the End If error, since it's limiting the behavior you're looking for. You can restructure like this and see if that helps clear things up. Basically what it does is, since you only have one action in the if, we can do it on-line, reducing the need for your End If's. Then we only need the End If for the ActiveSheet.Name check. I'd say give this a try and take a look at the reference below and see how that impacts what's going on.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
     If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then Call AutoFilter

     If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then Call AutoFilter
 End if
 End Sub
```

Reference: https://software-solutions-online.com/end-if-without-block-if/

Comment: Thank you!
I did manage to fix the error by removing a part of the code I (stupidly) did not include above... I had an 'Else If Call AutoFilter', which I think was the problem.